# Am I reclustering this table correctly? Variant type

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a window function tells me if a table contains : 
Value A, B or A&B within a cluster

For example:

I have created a JSON partition with an s3 bucket like this: s3://bucket_name/application_one/2016/07/01/11/

Table content for your example from:

SELECT * from Test_cluster limit 2;

```
Row  V    T
1
{ "city": { "coord": { "lat": 2.2673, "lon": 102.5453 }, "country": "MY", "id": 1732857, "name": "Tangkak" }, "data": [ { "clouds": 100, "deg": 82, "dt": 1571544000, "humidity": 50, ...
2019-10-19 23:35:37.000

2
{ "city": { "coord": { "lat": 2.0251, "lon": 103.3328 }, "country": "MY", "id": 1732811, "name": "Kluang" }, "data": [ { "clouds": 100, "deg": 155, "dt": 1571544000, "humidity": 69, ...
2019-10-19 23:35:37.000
```

What I tried:

```
ALTER  TABLE Test_Cluster CLUSTER BY (V, T);
ALTER  TABLE Test_Cluster RECLUSTER;
```

I am getting error that variant type is not supported, is there another format or cast I can use to recluster my variant Json table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clustering on a variant is not supported, but you can cluster on a variant expression.

See the example below from the snowflake documentation:

```
-- cluster by paths in variant columns
create or replace table t3 (t timestamp, v variant) cluster by (v:"Data":id::number);
```

Comment: Another suggestion: column t might contain too many discrete values so you may want an expression like to_date( t )

Comment: I tried to cluster on multiple expressions ...CLUSTER BY (V:"city":coord::string, V:"city"::string, V:"lat"::number, V:"lon"::number, V:"country"::string, V:"id"::number, V:"name"::string), but I wonder if at that point I should just convert the JSON column to a new table?

Comment: That is always a possibility.  Have you read the Snowflake guidelines for clustering?  A multi-column/expression key should be limited to two, maybe 3 columns/expressions.  The order and cardinality is very important. Think about how the table will be queried.  If time and city are often used, then they are good candidates for keys.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html#

Comment: Thank you Mike, I will read up on this and ask a new question if we run into any issues.